# Why am I getting this error with the below code?

Tags: mariadb, spring-jdbc

Why am I getting this error. I don't know where am I going wrong.

```
String query = "update admin set adm_name = ? where adm_id = ?";        
    //ResultSet rs;

    try {
        DBConnection dbc = new DBConnection();
        if(!dbc.connected) dbc.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement st = 
(dbc.con).prepareStatement(query);
        st.setString(1, a.getAdm_name());
        st.setString(2, a.getAdm_id());
        st.executeUpdate(query);

        st.close();
        (dbc.con).close();
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Error:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near '? where adm_id = ?' at line
>   1

The query runs well in phpmyadmin.

Comment: What is the value of `a.getAdm_name()`?

Comment: a is an object. I  have not posted full code here.

Comment: I'm not really a JDBC person, but why are you passing in the query into st.executeUpdate()?  As the statement is already prepared with the very same query string, the parameterless executeUpdate() variant looks like the right thing to call here?